# Mensagem "Undefined index" ao acessar índice do $_POST

Tags: php, html

```
<div class="modal fade" id="adcmodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h2 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Adicione a nota dos seus alunos</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="post" action= "index.php">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nome" class="control-label">Nome:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nome">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nota1" class="control-label">Nota1:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nota1">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nota2" class="control-label">Nota2:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nota2">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="nota3" class="control-label">Nota3:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nota3">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <form><button type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        <input type="submit" name="addbtn" value="Adicionar" class="btn btn-lg btn-sample"></form>

      </div>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
     <?php
    include("config.php");
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","alunos");
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];

    if (isset($_GET['addbtn'])) {

    $query = "INSERT INTO `aluno` (`id`, `nome`, `nota`, `nota2`, `nota3`) VALUES (NULL, $nome, '10', '20', '30')";

    mysqli_query($con, $query);
    }

    ?>
```

O que há de errado que não está detectando a parte  **$nome = $_POST['nome'];**?

Notice: Undefined index: nome in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 112

Comment: O POST só existe na hora que você envia o formulário, então você  também tem que verificar se existe o $_POST['nome']

Comment: if (isset($_GET['addbtn']) && isset($_POST['nome'])) {

Comment: Você coloca o botão submit fora do primeiro bloco <form></form> que é os que contém os campos. Tente colocar dentro dele e pode remover o segundo bloco <form></form>.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na primeira vez que você acessa a página, você está fazendo uma requisição HTTP utilizando o método GET, portanto não estarão definidas nenhuma informação na variável global `$_POST`. Desta forma, quando você tenta obter o valor de `$_POST["nome"]`, ele não existe, gerando o erro. Você só pode acessar este valor se o PHP estiver tratando uma requisição HTTP com o método POST. Para fazer esta verificação, basta fazer:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    ...
}
```

No seu caso, ficaria algo como:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    include("config.php");
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","alunos");
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];

    if (isset($_POST['addbtn'])) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO `aluno` (`id`, `nome`, `nota`, `nota2`, `nota3`) VALUES (NULL, $nome, '10', '20', '30')";
        mysqli_query($con, $query);
    }
}

?>
```

Perceba que eu alterei também de `$_GET["addbtn"]` para `$_POST["addbtn"]` pois seria o mais lógico para este caso. Aliás, no seu código HTML, o botão `addbtn` está em um formulário diferente dos campos. Não vejo isso fazer muito sentido. Acredito que você deveria deixá-lo no mesmo formulário que os campos de textos.

Comment: Opa, muito obrigado, só um detalhe: printando a váriavel **$nome** na inserção  eu deveria usar dessa forma **'".$nome."'** , correto? Ou existe outra?

Comment: @SkullFire Utilizando aspas duplas para string o PHP consegue analisar variáveis no seu interior, não necessitando fazer a concatenação. Então algo como `"insert into ... values (null, '$nome')"` já iria funcionar também.

Comment: Por incrivel que parece não funcionou dessa forma

Comment: @SkullFire deu algum erro?

Comment: Não, só não inseriou na tabela. Usando **'".$nome."'** enviou de boa.

Comment: Teria como o POST ser sem dado. Por exemplo `curl -X POST https://site.com` (ou com outros dados, sem o `nome`). Isso continuaria disparando o `notice` no `$nome = $_POST['nome'];`, por que continuaria não existindo, apesar do método ser POST. Acredito que seria ideal um `isset($_POST['nome'])`.